# Making function run async, makes async WCF call within that function run improperly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I am using Amazon SQS for image file upload. I have a function that checks for new SQS messages and read the messages in a loop and run a function

Code:

```
if (receiveMessageResponse.ReceiveMessageResult.Message.Count != 0)
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < receiveMessageResponse.ReceiveMessageResult.Message.Count; i++)
             {
                 string messageBody = receiveMessageResponse.ReceiveMessageResult.Message[i].Body; // read as json text
                 dynamic dynResult = JObject.Parse(messageBody);
                 ImageServiceReference.statePackage sp = new ImageServiceReference.statePackage();

                 ..... // some sp objevt initialization

                 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                  {
                      SaveImageProcedure(sp); 
                  });
          }
}
```

In the working code, I call `SaveImageProcedure` without a Task (synchronously). But now I wanted to make the `SaveImageProcedure` run asynchronously.

In that function SaveImageProcedure I have a task:

```
var task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(proxy.BeginSaveImage(sp, new AsyncCallback(CompleteSave), state), proxy.EndSaveImage);
```

this task calls a WCF Service that make long image processing asynchronously.

**My problem:**

When I use `Task.Factory.StartNew` to call the SaveImageProcedure asynchronously, the WCF doesn't process the images, whether when I run it without the `Task.Factory.StartNew` (just the function name itself), it runs fine and I see the image processed.

I can't figure out why when I made the change to run the SaveImageProcedure function async, it causes the WCF not to work as with running synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SaveImageProcedure` already is asynchronous as `Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync` is asynchronous. Why do you need the `Task.Factory.StartNew` around it? That will use an extra thread and once you use up all the threads in your thread pool the program will become very slow as the thread pool size is increased using a very slow hill climbing algorithm. I'd be curious to have a look at the number of threads in you program as that routine is running.

Comment: When I ran the task with  int res = task.Result; after the Task<int>.Factory... code , it waits for it to finish before it continues (used in a loop) and therefore the images are processed one by one for some reason . When I wrap the function with the async call inside a task, it processes the images in parallel. Why this is happen? It seems like it waits for the FromAsync to finish and then continue to the next loop iteration.

Comment: `task.Result` blocks until the task finishes which is why you are observing that behaviour. You should do `task.ContinueWith(t => int res = t.Result)` the 'ContinueWith` statement gets called after the task is complete so the task.Result won't block.